# subspace of $\mathbb R^4$.

Tags: vector-spaces

$W=\{(a,b,c,d)|ab=cd\}.$

How do I prove  that  $W$ is subspace of $\mathbb R^4$?

I have $(0,0,0,0)\in W$, so $W$ not empty.

and $k\in\mathbb R$,$w\in W$ so $kw\in W$.

so I'm not sure that if $w_1,w_2\in W$ so $w_1+w_2\in W$ ?

Comment: $(1,1,1,1)$ and $(2,3,6,1)$ are in $W$.  Is $(3,4,7,2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't, as it's not defined by linear relations.

*Counter-example*: set $\;w_1=(1,0,0,1)$, $w_2=(0,2,1,0)$. We have:
$$w_1+w_2=(1,2,1,1)$$
and it doesn't satisfy the relation.

Answer (score 2):

$(1,0,0,0) \in W$ because $1 \cdot 0 = 0 \cdot 0$.

Also

$(0, 1,0,0) \in W$ because $0 \cdot 1 = 0 \cdot 0$.

$(1,0,0,0)+(0,1,0,0)=(1,1,0,0)$ but $1\cdot 1 \ne 0 \cdot 0$.

Hence $W$ is not closed under addition.